# Найти все ветви с коммитами не слитыми в заданную ветвь

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Использую `git branch --no-merged master`, но это позволяет увидеть только локальные ветви. Имея более 60 ветвей, часть из которых заброшена, хотелось бы привести все в порядок с наименьшими затратами. Графическими инструментами пробегаться глазами по диаграммам достаточно тяжело.

Как найти все ветви с коммитами не слитыми с заданной ветвью в удаленном репозитории?

Comment: ветка (branch) в git — это не набор коммитов, а плавающий указатель на конкретный коммит. что именно вы подразумеваете под «неслитыми» ветками?

Comment: Как раз набор указателей мне и нужен.

Comment: `git branch -a ...` выдаст вам набор указателей.

Comment: Хорошо, вы натолкнули на более правильную формулировку: мне нужны все коммиты, которые не были смёржены в выбранную ветвь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте опцию `-a` (`--all`), про которую написано:

> List both remote-tracking branches and local branches.

вольный перевод:

> показывает и удалённые и локальные ветки.